# Base 64 decoding in Python and Oracle

Tags: oracle, python-2.7, oracle11g, base64, decoding

I am trying to replicate some `python 2.7` code in `Oracle` database.

When trying to replicate `base64 decoding`, I am getting different output.

**Python Code:**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import base64
print(base64.b64decode('rO0ABXVyAAJbQqzzF/gGCFTgAgAAeHAAAAAgGLCRnyhEZhzJJRd7EoVPp2XWTRgDNYHq4cAghvXvTaw='))
```

**Python Code Output:**

`�� ur [B���T�  xp    ���(Df�%{�O�e�M5���� ���M�`

**Oracle Query:**

`select utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(UTL_ENCODE.BASE64_DECODE(  UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW ('rO0ABXVyAAJbQqzzF/gGCFTgAgAAeHAAAAAgGLCRnyhEZhzJJRd7EoVPp2XWTRgDNYHq4cAghvXvTaw='))) from dual;`

**Oracle Query Output:**

`�ur[B��T�xp �Df�{��M5����`

The output seems to be partially same but not completely.

May be due to lack of knowledge, I am missing basics. Please suggest.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "replicate python code in oracle database"?

Comment: @DeepSpace, As previously this decoding was done in the python code, now doing in the Database.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently your BASE64 string encodes some binary data (i.e. not text). In this case `cast_to_varchar2` would be useless.

Try `TO_BLOB(UTL_ENCODE.BASE64_DECODE(UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW('rO0ABXVyAAJbQqzzF/gGCFTgAgAAeHAAAAAgGLCRnyhEZhzJJRd7EoVPp2XWTRgDNYHq4cAghvXvTaw=')))`

Comment: Thanks for your response, i have tried `to_blob(UTL_ENCODE.BASE64_DECODE( UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW ('rO0ABXVyAAJbQqzzF/gGCFTgAgAAeHAAAAAgGLCRnyhEZhzJJRd7EoVPp2XWTRgDNYHq4cAghvXvTaw=')))` and the output is `(BLOB)`, I need to see the output in text so then, I can compare.

Comment: I don't recommend to compare binary data as text, it is useless. You can compare the result with a HEX editor, perhaps you have to save it as a file before.

Comment: Thanks. yes, I think you are right. I have achieved the same using `UTL_ENCODE.TEXT_DECODE ` method and to compare we need to compare Hex values. I have added the same in answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved the same using `UTL_ENCODE.TEXT_DECODE` method and `AL32UTF8` as encode_charset .

```
 declare
 v2 varchar2(4000 char);
 begin
 v2 :=  UTL_ENCODE.TEXT_DECODE(
   'rO0ABXVyAAJbQqzzF/gGCFTgAgAAeHAAAAAgGLCRnyhEZhzJJRd7EoVPp2XWTRgDNYHq4cAghvXvTaw=', 
   'AL32UTF8', 
  UTL_ENCODE.BASE64);

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('v2='||v2);

  end;
```

**Output:**

`v2=��ur[B���T�xp ���(Df�%{�O�e�M5���� ���M�`

Comment: You should really not rely on this. Character `�` is just a placeholder for **any** invalid character, i.e. `�` can represent a various number of Byte combinations.