# ORA-28234: key length too short when doing AES encryption in Oracle

Tags: oracle, encryption, aes

I am trying to do AES encryption in Oracle and getting `ORA-28234: key length too short` error.

However, the length of the key is 32 and correct according to me.

`select length('���(Df�%{�O�e�M5���� ���M�') from dual;`

**Output:**

`32`

I have tried AES encryption with the same key in `python` and `postgres` and it's working fine.

Please suggest.

**Oracle AES Anonymous block:**

```
declare
 l_mod number;
 enc_val raw(2000);
begin
     l_mod:= dbms_crypto.ENCRYPT_AES + dbms_crypto.CHAIN_CBC+ dbms_crypto.AES_CBC_PKCS5;
     enc_val := dbms_crypto.encrypt(UTL_I18N.STRING_TO_RAW ('test',  'AL32UTF8'),l_mod,UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW ('���(Df�%{�O�e�M5���� ���M�'));
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('enc_val='||enc_val);

end;
```

**Output:**

```
Error report -
ORA-28234: key length too short
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_CRYPTO_FFI", line 3
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_CRYPTO", line 13
ORA-06512: at line 6
28234. 00000 -  "key length too short"
*Cause:    The key specified is too short for the algorithm. DES
           requires a key of at least 8 bytes. Triple DES requires a
           key of least 16 bytes in two-key mode and 24 bytes in three-key
           mode.
*Action:   Specify a longer key.
```

Comment: Whenever you are going to treat random bytes as text you are likely to loose information. Base 64 encoding, such as in one of the answers, is one way to avoid it (the other obvious one is not to convert to text at all, of course).

Answer (score 2):

According to [Base 64 decoding in Python and Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59750781/base-64-decoding-in-python-and-oracle) the code should be rather like this:

```
DECLARE
 l_mod NUMBER;
 enc_val RAW(2000);
 KEY VARCHAR2(80) := 'rO0ABXVyAAJbQqzzF/gGCFTgAgAAeHAAAAAgGLCRnyhEZhzJJRd7EoVPp2XWTRgDNYHq4cAghvXvTaw=';

BEGIN
    l_mod:= DBMS_CRYPTO.ENCRYPT_AES + DBMS_CRYPTO.CHAIN_CBC+ DBMS_CRYPTO.AES_CBC_PKCS5;
    enc_val := DBMS_CRYPTO.ENCRYPT(UTL_I18N.STRING_TO_RAW('test',  'AL32UTF8'), l_mod, UTL_ENCODE.BASE64_DECODE(UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW(KEY)) );
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('enc_val = '||enc_val);

END;
```